# sqlite: is it possible to get table row count in O(1) time?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, rowcount

`SELECT count(...) ...` appears to be O(n), although researching this I've seen people say it's faster if I pass an indexed column to count. That is not an option however, as there may be no indexes or primary keys on the table. I also don't want to be relying on rowid for this.

The closest I've been able to find is `SELECT sum(ncell) FROM dbstat WHERE name=...`, but A) it's not accurate, and B) it's still not O(1)

Does sqlite really not store table row counts anywhere? Seems like a simple thing to do...

Comment: No DBMS stores row counts. That would make no sense. How could you store a row count for a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause that is variable,  or a possible `JOIN` or `UNION`?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a row count.  You could create a second table with a row count, and use a trigger to keep it up to date on updates and deletes.

Comment: @KenWhite . . . That is not exactly true.  Many databases do actually store a good-enough approximation of the row count -- which is accurate in situations where the table is not changing and often good enough when it is.